# Как убрать обводку вокруг кнопки?

Tags: html, css

Вот фото:

[image]

Такая проблема: при нажатии на кнопку (показана на фоте, кнопка поднимается наверх до конца) вокруг кнопки образуется прерывистыми линиями квадрат, как его убрать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это фокус. Попробуйте объявить элемент нефокусируемым, если такое возможно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Код, приведенный ниже, уберет обводку, появляющуюся при клике на элемент.

```
a, a:visited, a:focus, a:active, a:hover{
    outline:0 none !important;
}
```

**Обновление**

Это нужно написать в ваш файл стилей (какое-то_название.css) или в `.html` файл в блоке `<head>`

```
<head>
<!-- Тут какие-то ваши теги... -->
<style type="text/css">
a, a:visited, a:focus, a:active, a:hover{
    outline:0 none !important;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: А куда писать? Ничего не понял

Comment: @Саша202020, это нужно написать в ваш файл стилей (какое-то_название.css) или в `.html` файл в блоке `<head>`

    <head>
    <!-- Тут какие-то ваши теги... -->
    <style type="text/css">
    a, a:visited, a:focus, a:active, a:hover{
        outline:0 none !important;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

Comment: Спасибо))) реально работает